# Get all employee detail from employees table whose "First_name" start with any single character between 'a-p'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    first_name LIKE 'A%'
    OR first_name LIKE 'B%'
    OR first_name LIKE 'C%'
    OR first_name LIKE 'D%'
ORDER BY
    first_name;
```

is there any new way to rewrite the SQL Query to find the first_name starting from A to P

Comment: Please add/tag the DB system you are working with since SQL dialects can vary.

Comment: you could try getting the first character then use an in clause where c in ('a','b'...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

```
select *
from employees
where regexp_like(first_name, '^[a-p]', 'i')
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` means "start of text"
- `[a-p]` means "any character in the range à to p inclusive"
- The `i` flag means "ignore case"

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that just

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM emp
  3     WHERE ename BETWEEN 'A' AND 'P'
  4  ORDER BY ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1265                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1680        300         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2993                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2818                    10
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3450                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        998                    30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       3421                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5750                    10
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1313       1400         30
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1495                    10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my  question But 
As per your above query am not getting the expected output 

SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE first_name  BETWEEN 'A' AND 'B'
ORDER BY first_name;

Result: Am getting the names only from letter A but in the employees table we have records in starting with B

104 Bruce
193 Britney

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR` to extract the first character and then compare that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'p'
ORDER BY
       first_name;
```

or you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  (first_name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'p' OR first_name LIKE 'p%')
ORDER BY
       first_name;
```

*(Which would use an index on `first_name`, whereas the first query would not use the index and, instead, would need a function-based index on `SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1)`.)*

Comment: Or just `first_name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'pz'`

Comment: @Bohemian That will not find names starting with `pza` though.

Comment: Then use `pzzzzzz`. There are no names starting with that.

Comment: @Bohemian In the OP's comment below, they say they have names such as `B 104` and `Bruce 193` so we are not restricted to names that occur in the real world (such as people who may call their child "X'nedra"). While I understand the point you are making, your approach of using `pzzzzzz` as an upper bound still has the potential to exclude results as it is making assumptions about the data set and those assumptions may not be true.

Comment: OK. I'm not that familiar with Oracle, but shouldn't your condition either be `lower(first_name) between 'a' and 'p'` or (assuming all names start with a capital letter) `first_name between 'A' and 'P'`?

Comment: @Bohemian The title of the question was "Get all employee detail from employees table whose `First_name` start with any single character between 'a-p'" and I answered that question. If the OP has a different question (such as any single character between `a-p` and `A-P`) then I can amend the answer to include that by adding, for example, `OR first_name BETWEEN 'A' AND 'P' OR first_name LIKE 'P%'` to the existing answer but that is not the question asked.